# Notify Stripe Checkout Payment Status to FrontEnd

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Iam making a basic react website that has a payment feature

So, Iam using Stripe Hosted Checkout page, so i used WebHooks to track events, but thats only on the server.
I want to notify or basically send a reponse to the frontend that the payment was successfully done and proceed with further operations

heres how iam creating a stripe session
//frontend

```
export default function Checkout() {

    async function toCheckOut(){
        fetch("/checkout", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(user),
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then((data)=>{
            window.location.href = data.url;
        })
      }
    
      let user = {
        prod_name: "FlimFair Monthly Subscription",
        price: "49",
        id: "price_1OJsBfSAzab3NSzcquCNBDJJ"
      }


  return (
    <div>
        <button type='button'>Redirect To Checkout</button>
        <button type='button' onClick={toCheckOut}>Checkout</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

//server

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_************************************************************************************************');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());


//WEBHOOK
        app.post("/hooks", express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (req,res)=>{
            let signingsecret = "whsec_70a70718d689eff658076268d708ed65c6d610f0f8edd23742efbe5bdc7e5119"
        
            const payload = req.body
            const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
        
            //matching
            let event 
            try{
                event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload,sig,signingsecret)
            } catch(e){
                console.log("Attention PIYUSH WEBHOOK ERROR (line 235)" + e);
                res.status(400).json({success: false});
                return
            }
        
            //if successfull i.e no error

            res.status(200).json({success:true})


            switch (event.type) {
                case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
                  const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
                  console.log(`PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful! hoooorrrryaaaaay!!!!!!!!!`);
                  res.json("PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful! hoooorrrryaaaaay!!!!!!!!!")
                  // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
                  // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
                  break;

                case 'customer.subscription.created':
                  const subscription_created = event.data.object;
                  console.log("Subscription Created successfully hoooorrrryaaaaay!!!!!!!!!")
                  res.json("PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful! hoooorrrryaaaaay!!!!!!!!!")
                  break;

                case 'payment_method.attached':
                  const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
                  console.log("payment method webhook triggered")
                  // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
                  // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
                  break;

                case 'checkout.session.async_payment_failed':
                    const checkoutSessionAsyncPaymentFailed = event.data.object;
                    console.log("checkout session payment failed");
                    // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.async_payment_failed
                    break;

                case 'checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded':
                    const checkoutSessionAsyncPaymentSucceeded = event.data.object;
                    console.log("checkout session payment succeeded");
                    // Then define and call a function to handle the event checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded
                    break;
                    
                default:
                  // Unexpected event type
                //   console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
                console.log('Unhandled event type');
              }
        
          })

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(require('body-parser').text({type: '*/*'}));


app.post('/checkout', async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body;
    try {
        console.log("new request------------------------------------------------------->")
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            line_items: [
                {
                    price: user.id,
                    quantity: 1,
                },
            ],
            mode: 'subscription',
            success_url: `http://localhost:3000/success`,
            cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000/cancel`,
        });

        res.json({ url: session.url });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
    }
});



app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running successfully on port no. ${port}`);
})
```

So, everything is working as expected, webhooks are functioning.
I just want to send a response to the client informing whether the payment was successfull or not

I tried finding answer to my question but instead ended up getting more confused

Comment: Once the payment is completed in a Checkout Session, customer will be redirected to your `success_url` ([doc](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=stripe-hosted#success-page)). Your system can then retrieve the Checkout Session to check its status.